# How can I change T to Flux<T> for a controller's method's return type?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a method looks like this.

```java
@GetMapping
Some read() {
    return getSome();
}
```

Now I want to change the result's type as a `Mono` as leave the `getSome()` non-reactive.

The question is which one is better? Or are they equivalent in the context of reactive system?

```java
@GetMapping
Mono<Some> read() {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(getSome()); // getSome() is still non-reactive
}

@GetMapping
Mono<Some> read() {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> getSome()); // getSome() is still non-reactive
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much equivalent. However, `Mono.fromSupplier` is more readable in cases when the `Mono` value is produced by a `Supplier`:

```
Mono.fromSupplier(this::getSome);
```

`Mono.justOrEmpty` would be a good fit for something like this:

```java
Some some;
Mono.justOrEmpty(some);
```